# Найти время переходного процесса Matlab

Tags: matlab

Имеется программный код:

```
clc,close

A = [-21.2, -160.3, -191.2;2.25, 5.67, 6.78;0, 7, 8];
B = [9.9;16.2;-3];
C = [0,0,1];
D = 0;
S1 = ss(A,B,C,D);

% ПЕРЕХОДНЫЙ ПРОЦЕСС ПО ОТРАБОТКЕ НАЧАЛЬНЫХ УСЛОВИЙ ПО ВСЕМ ПЕРЕМЕННЫМ СОСТОЯНИЯ
figure(1)
t = linspace(0,20,1000); u = exp(-0.2*t).*cos(3*t);
x0 = [5;-5;10];

lsim(S1,u,t,x0); 
grid on;
h7 = findobj('type','line'); 
set(h7,'linew', 1);
set(gcf,'color','w')
```

Необходимо найти время переходного процесса(по оси абсцисс) от первого пересечения эпсилона до последнего(на картинке)[image: Необходимо найти Tp]

Comment: что такое первое и последнее пересечения епсилона?

Comment: Это точки, где функция первый раз и последний раз пересикает Эпсилоны. По сути, нужно как-то найти  точки пересечения графика функции и двух этих прямых и вычесть. Но из-за плохого знания матлаба не получается это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
    clc,close

    A = [-21.2, -160.3, -191.2;2.25, 5.67, 6.78;0, 7, 8];
    B = [9.9;16.2;-3];
    C = [0,0,1];
    D = 0;
    S1 = ss(A,B,C,D);

    % ПЕРЕХОДНЫЙ ПРОЦЕСС ПО ОТРАБОТКЕ НАЧАЛЬНЫХ УСЛОВИЙ ПО ВСЕМ ПЕРЕМЕННЫМ СОСТОЯНИЯ
    figure(1)
    t = linspace(0,20,10000); u = exp(-0.2*t).*cos(3*t);
    x0 = [5;-5;10];

    [y,t]=lsim(S1,u,t,x0); 

    epsilon = 4;
    diff= abs(y)>epsilon;
    perehod = abs(diff(1:end-1)-diff(2:end));
    perehod_index= find(perehod);
    plot(t,y,t,y*0+epsilon,t,y*0-epsilon);
    hold on; grid on
    first_index= perehod_index(1);
    last_index= perehod_index(end);
    h=line([t(first_index) t(first_index)],[0 y(first_index)]);
    h.LineWidth= 2; h.Color= 'black'
    h=line([t(last_index) t(last_index)],[0 y(last_index)]);
    h.LineWidth= 2; h.Color= 'black'
    Tp= t(last_index)-t(first_index)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду разбираться